# View did appear not called when view controller (SideMenu)

Tags: ios, swift, email, viewdidappear

I have been implementing [SideMenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu) in my iOS app (mailbox). The SideMenu is used to choose the current folder. I created a SideMenu navigation controller and attached a `UITableViewController` as the root vc.

It works perfectly fine, up until the point where I click on one of the cells, which dismisses the side menu and should load the mail in the original view controller. However, the original view controller's `viewDidAppear` method is not called. When I tried to call the load function directly, Xcode said that my `tableView` was nil (it wasn't when it first loaded).

Here is my code for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in the SideMenu table:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    currentFolder = folders[indexPath.row].path
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mail") as! MailViewController
        vc.loadMail()
    }

}
```

Here is the `loadMail` function in the original vc:

```
func loadMail(showsSpinner: Bool = true) {
    ...
    if let messages = fetchedMessages as? [MCOIMAPMessage] {
        self.mailsInFolder = messages
        SwiftSpinner.hide()
        self.refresher.endRefreshing()
        self.table.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Also, here is `viewDidAppear` in the original vc:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    print("viewDidAppear")
    let from = self.navigationController?.transitionCoordinator?.viewController(forKey: .from)
    if from is MessageViewController {
        print("from is message controller")//should not load
        return
    }
    self.loadMail()

}
```

Here, `viewDidAppear` is not called, and the mail doesn't load. What can I do to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: `instantiateViewController` does not mean `viewDidLoad` is called.

Comment: @creeperspeak how would I call it then?

Comment: Why not just put the `loadMail` function inside `viewDidLoad` in your `MailViewController`.  And instead of just instantiating and not doing anything with `MailViewController`, just present it.  Either make a storyboard segue and perform the segue, or present the `MailVC` manually (either modally or in a navigation controller, or whatever).  Does that help?

Comment: I need to call loadMail repeatedly (outside of viewDidLoad). Also, viewDidLoad is not called.

Answer (score -1):

I had been working with SideMenu for a while, and I suggest you to use as `mainViewController` a UINavigationController and then when select one cell of your tableView in the rightViewController

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    currentFolder = folders[indexPath.row].path
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mail") as! MailViewController
    {
       mainNavController.setViewControllers([vc], animated: false)
    }
    homeSlide.slideMenuController()?.closeLeft()
}
```

I hope this helps you, best regards

Comment: I'm slightly confused about the variables you used... could you explain further? It doesn't seem to be compiling right now.

Comment: could you define the variables please? Thanks.

Comment: @penatheboss what is your containerViewController configuration? can you share your code where you setup your right menu and mainViewController?

Comment: i didnt code it; i set it up through the storyboard

Comment: @penatheboss but your mainViewController is an UINavigationController?

Comment: No, MailViewController is a UIViewController. I have a separate navigation controller for this.

Comment: Well, I will update my answer as soon as i can, and show you how I use the SideMenu class, maybe can help you

Comment: @penatheboss did you finally solve this? sorry I was very busy